# Cannot store raster in custom database schema

Tags: postgis, postgresql, dem, raster2pgsql

I want to store an elevation raster in a postgis database. However a problem occurs. I use the following command:

`raster2pgsql -I -C -e -Y -F -s 4326 -t auto dem.tif schemaname.filename | psql -U blabla -d blabla -h localhost -p 5432`

As long as I put the raster in the public schema, the command works properly. But when I change the schema name to some other database schema I have created, the command just returns `ERROR: schema "schemaname" does not exist`.

Do I overlook something?

Edit: the full error looks like this:

`ERROR:  schema "schemaname" does not exist
ERROR:  schema "schemaname" does not exist
invalid command \.
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "0100000100"
LINE 1: 0100000100B5EDD83C22BEF33E0CC0E6158FFAF2BE5981483035A34FC08E...
        ^
ERROR:  schema "schemaname" does not exist
ERROR:  The value provided for schema is invalid
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function addrasterconstraints(name,name,name,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean,boolean) line 53 at RETURN`

Comment: This might be basic, but have you verified you are putting these into the same database as where you created the schemas?  Also, have you checked permissions?

Comment: I'm certain of both points. I already stored tables with vector data in the DB in all schemas, so it seems this is not a permission issue.

Answer (score 1):

What is the actual schema name? Can you paste the output of `\dn+`. And try to run `raster2pgsql` with `-Y` which will use `COPY` instead of `INSERT`. There is a `raster2pgsql` argument (`-q`) that wraps the identifiers with quotes too, it may be worth trying this.